# Error while creating ruby 1.9 hash

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, hash

On creating a ruby 1.9.2 hash syntax using number as a key for example

```
day = {1: "Sunday", 2: "Monday"}
```

I am getting the following error

```
syntax error, unexpected '}', expecting end-of-input
```

But it works fine when i use hash syntax in this format.

```
day = {one: "Sunday", two: "Monday"}
```

The ruby version I am using is 2.0.0p247

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Why I am getting this error? 
 error, unexpected '}', expecting end-of-input

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
day = {one: "Sunday", two: "Monday"}
```

is the new syntax comes from version 1.9, which is same as

```
day = {:one =>  "Sunday", :two => "Monday"}
```

Only the key is **symbol** you could use the that syntax.

You have to use `day = {1 => "Sunday", 2 => "Monday"}` in your case.

Answer (score 2):

You have to use the `key => value` syntax if your keys are not symbols:

```
day = {1 => "Sunday", 2 => "Monday"}
#=> {1=>"Sunday", 2=>"Monday"}
```

Comment: It would be great if it is explained why `one:` is treated as a `symbol` while `1:` isn't (during `Hash` instance creation)

Comment: @Bala: it *is* interpreted as a `Symbol`, but `:1` is not a legal `Symbol` literal. That's why there is a `SyntaxError`. The new `Hash` literal syntax was meant as a transitional feature towards keyword arguments, therefore it only works for `Symbol`s which are also valid Ruby labels.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a hash in that way

```
day={}
day[:one] = "Sunday"
day[:two] = "Monday"
```